# Error in VS Code studio when using Javascript in the git bash in terminal section

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, git-bash

```
prati@LAPTOP-A2ET79D1 MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/WEB D/2.2+Native+Modules
```

$ node index.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1152
throw err;
^

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\prati\OneDrive\Desktop\WEB D\2.2+Native+Modules\index.js'
> at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:15)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> requireStack: []
> }

Node.js v21.6.1

this error
what can i do

[image]

so i am using VS Code studio for my web dev project
i install git bash and node js to use javascript in it
at the terminal i select bash and make a directory
in the directory i create a file namely index.js  in which i wrote console.log ("hello");
now i am using the command node index.js to run javascript
after writing node index.js it should show hello  but it is showing an error

Comment: Have you changed directory in bash to the one containing the index file? The error is saying that it can't find the file.

Comment: My experience with git-bash on windows is, it's great for doing git and ssh things, but it's not perfect for executing native windows apps, as it has different path schemes and eviroment. Have you tried a different shell, e.g. powershell?